# Admob doesn't work

Tags: java, android, admob

This is my `MainActivity`, there is a `mainView` in the game
and the `adView` is the admob (work correctly alone).
Game and admob works fine respectively， but not together.

```
package net.canarolab.puzzleroad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // private AdView adView;
    private MainView mainView;
    private final int MENU_SELECT_RESET = 1, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT = 2;

    // MUSICA
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;// para musica de fondo (se declara aqui para que
                            // pueda

    // utilizarla todos nuestros metodos)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //ADMOB
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        // Create the adView
        // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2f8fe3af5a6");
        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(request);


        // MUSIC
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.merry);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        mediaPlayer.start();


        //MAINVIEW
        // TURN OFF THE TITLE
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Apago la barra de estado
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Activity Quiero solo tapa
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // View Establezca el

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        mainView = new MainView(this);
        layout1.addView(mainView);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_RESET, 0, "Reset");
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT, 0, "Contact");
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Leí el recuento juego
        this.mainView.gameCount.read();
        Log.d("", "read");
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();

        // Escribo el recuento de juego.
        this.mainView.gameCount.save();
        Log.d("", "save");

        super.onPause();
        // No voy a desaparecer en esta actitud no hay más.
        // finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        super.onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_SELECT_RESET:
            this.mainView.gameCount.reset();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Has been reset．", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case MENU_SELECT_CONTACT:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "idea");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text of email");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { " trabajonacho33@gmail.com" });
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }}
```

**and this is my activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**I can't see the `mainView` and `adView` in the same layout.**
I need to mix in the same screen but I don't know how.
I need to change `setContentView` to be in xml.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace fill_parent with match_parent everywhere. Never use fill_parent, as it is deprecated.

Try to set the height of linearLayout and mainView to a specific value like 150dip (as a test). Do they show together now?

You should not use System.exit(0) in general, so think of another way of closing you app. By looking at the current code, I don't think you need anything like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use layout to show your add.Just put below code in your layout where ever you want into the screen.
       <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

     <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="Your AddMob ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE" />  
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And add AdmobSDK.jar into you libs folder

Comment: On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the layout width and height for the admob view before adding it to the layout 
`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);`

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`
    adView.setLayoutParams(lay);`layout.addView(adView);`